# How to find the average in a do-while loop

Tags: java

I have to write a program that asks the user to enter an integer value. After each value, the user has to respond with a "y" or a "n" if he/she wants to continue with the program, and each number the user enters is stated as either odd or even.

I have done this so far with a do-while loop, but I am confused on how to get the averages of the values the user enters. How would you get the average for all the numbers entered?

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ProgramTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer = "";

        do {

            int num, count = 0;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
            System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
            num = scan.nextInt();

            if ((num % 2) == 0) System.out.println(num + " is an even number.");
            else System.out.println(num + " is an odd number");
            System.out.println("do you want to continue?");
            answer = scan.next();
            count++;

        } while (answer.equals("y"));

    }
}
```

Comment: To calculate the average you need 2 things: 1. sum of already entered numbers, 2. count of already entered numbers. Just divide them both (checking if count !=) after user enters "n".

Comment: The mean (which is I guess the average you mean) is the sum of the numbers divided by the number of numbers. So, just accumulate those values in the loop, and divide them once the user does not answer `"y"`.

Comment: Do you need the average after every step, or only when you want to not continue any longer?

Comment: I need the average when I don't want to continue any longer.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: Technically you just need a variable outside the loop called `int sum = 0;`, the numbers you read in are added to it `sum += num;`, and then the average is just `System.out.println("" + ((((Integer)sum).floatValue())/count));` (although technically if you specify the `sum` as `float` then you don't have to do this hideous casting)

Comment: Coding the average amount is `float sum = 0;` ... `sum += num;` ... `float average = sum / count;`

Answer (score 2):

**From the Question looks like following things need to handled,**

> 1. haven't add mechanism for addition into single variable.
> 2. put all variable to out from do...while loop body...
> 3. created additional variable according to requirement.

*see all this things covered by me with following code snippet.*

do something likewise,

```
String answer = "";
double sum = 0; // use for storing addition to all entered values..
int num, count = 0;
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
            num = scan.nextInt(); // getting input from user through console
            sum = sum + num; // add every input number into sum-variable
            if ((num % 2) == 0) System.out.println(num + " is an even number.");
            else System.out.println(num + " is an odd number");
            System.out.println("do you want to continue?");
            answer = scan.next(); // ask for still want to repeat..
            count++;

        } while (answer.equals("y"));
System.out.println("Average is : " + sum + "/" + count + " = "+ (sum /count));
```

Comment: your variable `avg` is actually a `sum`.

Comment: yup... you are right. user can give it as per their convenient way.

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* this code fixes the problem.  This only says to "copy this code".  You should explain what the issue actually is *first*.

Comment: You're also not going to have a good time with `scan.next()`, since that doesn't consume the newline character.

Comment: Let me do it. Thank you. i think it will also enhance for future user.

Comment: Edited, let me know still any improvement needed then. most welcome

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate Average, you need 2 things: Sum of all numbers and Count of all numbers involved in the Average calculation.

Your `sum` and `count` which involved in the Average calculation needs to be out of the `do..while` scope in order for them to be **known** at the calculation stage.

I also took the liberty of fixing your code a little bit

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ProgramTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        String answer = "";
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
            int num = scan.nextInt();

            boolean isEven = (num % 2 == 0);

            System.out.println(num + " is an " + (isEven ? "even" : "odd") + " number.");
            sum += num;

            System.out.println("do you want to continue?");
            answer = scan.next();
            count++;
        } while (answer.toLowerCase().equals("y"));

        System.out.println("Average: " + (sum/count));
    }
}
```

Comment: sum and count are out of scope

Comment: Thanks, Now it's fixed.

Comment: it says the toLower symbol cannot be found

Comment: I'm didn't up-vote/down-vote no one, and i aspect the rest will do the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron, Fixed to `toLowerCase()`

Answer (score -3):

Change your code like this:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
    class ProgramTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String answer = "";
            int avr =0;
            int num, count = 0;
            do {

                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
                System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
                num = scan.nextInt();

                if ((num % 2) == 0) System.out.println(num + " is an even number.");
                else System.out.println(num + " is an odd number");
                System.out.println("do you want to continue?");
                avr += num;
                answer = scan.next();
                count++;

            } while (answer.equals("y"));
           avr = avr /count;
     System.out.println("The avreage of value is:" + avr );
        }
    }
```

avr is average. that means when you input an integer. we add num and avr . and when finish looping. we divideto count. like this:

1-5-9-11

avr = 1+5+9+11;

count = 4;

avr = avr/4;

Comment: `count` is out of scope

Comment: It says the count symbol cannot be found

Comment: i change that.do you have any problem?

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* this code fixes the problem.  This only says to "copy this code".  You should explain what the issue actually is *first*.